# How to place inline-block divs one per line with CSS?

Tags: css, positioning, display

I am working on this page http://www.donchisciotte-lucca.it/it/offerte

and as you can see I want to have the 4 pictures, with 3 divs over each of them (a title, a description and a button).
I have put the 3 divs in inline-block in order to center them vertically over the single picture, but they display all in the same line. They should be one per line, but everything I tried does not work.

How can I solve this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Add a `<br>` between

Comment: I would like to solve it with CSS, so I can't use html code

Comment: You should wrap the entire thing in an inline-block div, not each of the three elements. Center the wrapper div. Then just type as usual and each thing can be on its own line (or use display:block).

Comment: @RachelS Post that suggestion and I'll upvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either way, I think you will be looking at a work-around, but I think it might make more sense to use `display:block` and find a way to get the right vertical spacing, rather than using `display:inline-block` and having to force them on different lines. So what about making the `.offerte .g-array-item div` items `display:block` and then giving them a % margin-top, for instance: `margin-top:30%`.

Try that out and see how it looks?

Comment: Thank you, I used display: block for all the divs, and used padding-top for the title (with the margin it gave problems), so the title pushes down also the description and the button. Then I made sure to make the description space big enough so that the number of lines does not influence it

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the entire thing in a `display:inline-block` div, not each of the three elements with its own. Center the wrapper div with whatever you used. Then just type as usual and each thing can be on its own line (or use `display:block`).

Here is a simple sample demonstrate it

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgray;
}
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Img</span>
  <span>Text</span>
  <span>Button</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with display:block the vertical align did not work fine, but with that, plus some manual sizing and padding instead of automatic align, as the other answer suggests, I managed to do it.